# How to draw the complete map in Carbon with React?

Tags: reactjs, charts, carbon-design-system

I want to use Carbon's [ExperimentalChoropletChart](https://charts.carbondesignsystem.com/react/?path=/story/complex-charts-choropleth-experimental--missing-data) in React to draw a map of Europe, the fact is that for said map I only have data from several countries, so the map, although I give it all the necessary polygons, only draws those countries for which you have data.

In this [environment](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sluwnc?file=src%2Foptions.js,src%2Fdata.js,src%2Findex.js) the problem is simplified: I have polygons for Spain, France and Italy, but as you can see it only draws the countries for which it has data and partially France.

I was wondering if there was a way to force the component to draw all polygons and only color those for which it has data.

I have tried setting the values ​​to 0, with a NaN or just declaring the name.

I have tried to compare what I have with what the environment offers without manipulation and I did not find anything beyond the properties of the polygons, but I do not know how to extrapolate it or how to draw a conclusion that allows me to obtain that information for the rest of the countries.